# How to remove the url param after it was completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url, sails.js

I am trying to remove the url param after function was completed, so it won't break the uix.

Here how it looks if param is not removed
`http://localhost:1337/check?domain=fb.com&success=task&success=note` .
I need it to look like this `http://localhost:1337/check?domain=fb.com&success=task` after every call.
Will be glad for help

Comment: From your question, it isn't clear that you understand how HTTP GET is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the URL search query string by `window.location.search` and parse it with [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).
2. Use `getAll(name)` to get all values of the parameter as an array.
3. Remove the desired element from the array.
4. Edit it back in with `set(name, value)`
5. Then use `window.location` to change the URL with `toString()`'s result (back as a string).

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const success = searchParams.getAll('success')
success.pop(); // ['task']
searchParams.set('success', success);
window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
```